# exporting data in excel using listview vb 6.0

Tags: vb6, export-to-excel

[image]

I'm new to vb 6.0 this is an existing project.

Suddenly the hardisk was corrupt so i take backup form sever and run in new hard disk and when the project run there is no issue but when ctrl+F5 (compile) OR build exe get this error given below.

Is there any reference missing or need to add[image]

Comment: Please remove the 'vb.net' tag! - VB6 and vb.net are different languages.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of tags before using them. The VB.NET tag explicitly states that it is not to be used for VB6 questions.

Comment: Don't post code or error messages as pictures. Post the relevant code as text, formatted as code, and post error messages as text, formatted appropriately. Add screenshots on top of that if and only if they add value.

Comment: In Project | Components, do you have `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)` selected?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes i already selected the Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a component `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)`.

Go to `Projects -> Components (Ctrl+ T)` and check the checkbox for it.

[image: Project -> Components]

[image: Add Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)]

Once this is added, you will also see extra components in the available GUI elements.

[image: New components]

Comment: Those components appear to be in the toolbox in the pic provided by the OP.  Although the pic doesn't provide info about which service pack (sp6 or otherwise) is installed.

Comment: I did not test with other SPs but `ListSubItem` starts working when I add SP6.  I can test it with whatever version the OP has.

Comment: Yes i already added this component

Comment: Does it still not work?  Try creating a test project with `ListSubItem` and see if that builds.  What other components do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the screenshot it looks like you have referenced both OCX Libraries

- Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 (SP2) - comctl32.ocx
- Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) - mscomctl.ocx

You can only use the `ListSubItems` collection with the Common Controls 6.0. If you want't to check which one is in use, you can open the .frm file in a TextEditor and search for the control name.
In front of the name you see either `ComctlLib.ListView` (5.0) or `MSComctlLib.ListView` (6.0)

You can also try to change the Library in the TextEditor. It worked with a sample project for me, but I'm not sure if there are properties used in your project that could break after the "switch" to the 6.0 controls.